# 母に七時に(a - 起きて・b - 起こして) 欲しいと頼んでおこう。

Tags: meaning

母に七時に(a - 起きて・b - 起こして) 欲しいと頼んでおこう。

For the above statement I chose a - 起きて but it was wrong, why is b right and a wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatically, both a and b are possible. It is a matter of which situation is (by far) the commoner.

- 起きてほしい would mean *ask mom to wake up*;
- 起こしてほしい would mean *ask mom to wake **me** up*,

of which the latter is the likelier.

Comment: So what your trying to tell me is that  起きて is intransitive and 起こして is transitive, correct?

Comment: That is correct, More succinctly they correspond to rise/raise.